# mysql prepared statement set default value for insert

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with two columns that links a row id from one table to a row id of another, basically I need to be able to insert multiple rows on this table where one column is a fixed value for the insert and the other changes. The insert is done in php using prepared statements and there is an unknown number of rows to be inserted (I've solved this part using call_user_func_array).

Here is an example of what I need to do:

example_table (column_A, column_B)

The insert:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (column_A, column_B) VALUES(a, b), VALUES(a, c), VALUES(a, d);
```

Translated to prepared statement:

`INSERT INTO example_table (column_A, column_B) VALUES(?, ?), VALUES(?, ?), VALUES(?, ?);`

values on bind_param:

```
('ssssss', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd')
```

As you can see the repetition of 'a'. is there a way to store 'a' and default it to column_A for the current insert only?

example of what i would like to do on bind_param:

```
('ssss', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Where 'a' above is used for column_A on all rows inserted (3 rows in the example). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No*, it's *not possible* to "alias" a value multiple times. Each placeholder is *unique* and must be bound to exactly one value. (It is not even possible to do this reliably with named parameters in PDO.)

If automatically building SQL dynamically (with placeholders) and associated data array, then there is no issue with such "duplication" as it's already handled by the generator.

If transactions are correctly used - which they should be anyway! - then simply calling INSERT in a loop, once for each pair, will likely have similar performance. This avoids needing to build the dynamic SQL (with placeholders) itself, but can increase latency as each command needs to round-trip to the SQL server.

If finding a bunch of such repetition, it might be time to *use a Data Access Layer* to hind such details; write it, test it, move onto something interesting.

---

In response to the comment about using SQL variables:

While the following will *not* improve performance, excepting possibly for ridiculously large values of @v, and makes the code more difficult to understand - it ought to be possible to use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) in a single insert statement. For instance, consider:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (@v := ?, ?), (@v, ?), (@v, ?)
```

This is ["valid" in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20233/1) (and is also MySQL-specific), where the placeholders are valid expressions; if it works will depend on how/if such a binding is allowed in a prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I've got a function that removes any duplication so that's not an issue. However my main concern is the time of execution for the script as there may be hundreds of rows inserted at a time. Any suggestions to make this process as efficient as possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3908399 I would first write it with a simple loop *and* using a transaction outside (and encompassing) the loop and all the inserts. Then test the performance - if it was sufficient, I would leave it as it. If it wasn't, I would find out why. A combined insert can reduce the overhead of processing multiple commands (and awaiting the responses) from the server, which makes a big difference over higher-latency connections, but it might not be a relevant factor or matter. Now, if there are tens of thousands of rows..

Comment: Hmmm... I guess that's about the only option that I do have then. One last thing to clear my mind on this..There isn't any way of storing a variable in the SQL itself and using the variable on the values? Example: 
`INSERT INTO example_table (column_A, column_B) VALUES(some_variable, ?), VALUES(some_variable, ?), VALUES(some_variable, ?);`

Comment: @user3908399 That's an interesting idea. I've added an excerpt to my response. However, I believe that these attempts are trying to solve a problem that *doesn't exist* or *exists elsewhere*.

Comment: Thank you it works! :) One more thing is this method concurrency safe?

Comment: The single insert is itself wrapped in an implicit transaction, and the variable is visible only in that connection - so in that sense, yes. As far as if the entire operation is "concurrency safe" of if the correct constraints have been established; that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try making a temporary table:

```
$query='CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable(column_B VARCHAR(50));';
$mysqli->query($query);
```

then insert unique values of column_B into this table

and finally

```
$query="INSERT INTO example_table (column_A, column_B) select $a , column_B from tempTable";
$mysqli->query($query);
```